# How to add aditional actions to argument into environement

Tags: environments, memoir, environment-variables

I am starting in LaTeX. I want to write a document and define some styles.

In this case I want to do two things with **one portion** of a paragraph:

1. That it has a red color
2. That it is aligned to the right

My problem is that I don't know how to do both when defining the environment.

This is my code:

```
%Define color
\newcommand{\txtred}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}

%Command to use in the context
\newcommand{\atright}[1]{\renewcommand{\atright}{#1}}

\newenvironment{txtbook}
    {\begin{flushleft}}
        {\txtred{\atright}
    \end{flushleft}
}
```

In the context:

```
\begin{txtbook}Del libro del Génesis \hfill \atright{9, 8-15}\end{txtbook}
```

This works, but I want to translate `\hfill` to the environment, but I don't know how to do it.

I am using memoir, if there is some simpler way to do what I want I would appreciate it.

There is one example, at right, there is the argument:

[image]

Comment: Are you able to mock up some examples of what the expected output should look like? Even if you do it in Word (or some other Wysiwyg editor)... consider provide sufficient examples that cover all possible use cases. Can you do that?

Comment: @Werner I added one image at end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really wish to use an environment and your current interface, the following will suffice:

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{xcolor,lipsum}

\newcommand{\txtred}{\textcolor{red}}
\newcommand{\atright}{\mbox{}\hfill\txtred}
\newenvironment{txtbook}{%
  \raggedright
}{%
  \unskip\par
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{txtbook}
  Del libro del Génesis \atright{9, 8-15}
\end{txtbook}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

One can add some spacing adjustments, if needed.

Comment: Ok, I prefer this approach, because I need to set another things into the environment. Thanks.

Comment: Do you know who I can add one additional space after the paragraph with `txtbook` environment? If I add this into de environment: `\setlength{\parskip}{1\baselineskip}` the space is placed on top of the paragraph, but I need it on bottom.

Comment: @A.Cedano: Try [this code](https://pastebin.com/raw/tgJ2bE6V).

Comment: It's working fine. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

I'd use a command, rather than an environment.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text

\newcommand{\txtbook}[2]{%
  \par\addvspace{\topsep}
  {\centering #1\hfill\textcolor{red}{#2}\par}\nopagebreak
  \addvspace{\topsep}
}

\begin{document}

\txtbook{Del libro del Génesis}{9, 8-15}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It works exactly how I want it. Although, if I try to put the paragraph in an environment it stops working. I suppose I would have to raise that question separately?

Comment: @A.Cedano I can only guess what you want to achieve…